# What is the record for highest successful (automated) CW transmission rate?

Tags: cw

I understand high speed CW is used with meteor scatter, because the path only exists for a few seconds after the meteor passes.

I was wondering if automated high speed CW has an effective "speed limit". I suppose bandwidth regulation would impose a theoretical limit for a noiseless channel and while that is relevant, I am looking for a more practical answer.

What is the record for the highest CW wpm rate that has been successfully achieved in amateur communications?

Comment: Given enough digital processing (SDR) for optimal pulse shaping to stay within the legal bandwidth for transmission and some oversampling on the receive end, the WPM limit for a noiseless channel would pretty much be limited by that bandwidth.

Comment: As you seem to understand that the maximum theoretical limit is imposed by bandwidth, all that's left are environmental conditions. It boils down to "has anyone ever cared to try this?" and "how much noise was there and transmitter power available?"

Comment: Yes, @PhilFrost I want to know if anyone has tried to set a CW speed record, or if there is a group sponsoring a CW speed contest, etc... I would note that theoretical limits sometimes assume for mathematical convenience some rather particular things about noise in order to get a result. That is why I was interested in practical answers and actual speed records.

Answer (score 1):

For 2013 looks like EU7KQ Nikolai Gelyasevich with a score of 297

source http://www.hst2013.eu/TX.pdf

Comment: Are these *automated* transmissions? It sounds to me like people copying by ear, though they may type the results on computer.

Comment: According to the rules this is all by hand. Either straight key or electronic key (Iambic).

http://www.hst2013.eu/HST%20Rules-%2024.10.2012.pdf

Comment: Is that 297 wpm? That's incredible.  Conversational speaking is around 150 wpm according to one source.